# Verify the value of a key in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I've been looking everywhere but haven't found an *easy* and robust way yet.

Task: I'm a QA and I'm trying to verify that specific keys have the expected value in a MongoDB document. If not, assert false.

My problem: My documents contain arrays and documents. Traversing down the tree is easy in the UI using dot notation (e.g. item.fruit.apples.type.macintosh). But in Java the only way I can do this is if I explicitly tell it whether item, fruit, apples, type, or macintosh is a document or an array. For example:

```
{
    "item": {
        "fruit",
        "apples"[
            "type": "macintosh",
            ]
    }
}
```

```
Document fruit  = doc.getEmbedded(List.of(item, fruit), Document.class);

List<Document> apples = (List<Document>) fruit.get(apples);
for (Document apple : apples) {
    actualValue = apple.getString("type");
    }
if(!actualValue.equals(expectedValue)) {
    Assert.fail();
    }
```

If a developer decides to change or remove any of the keys my verification will break. Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With the help from other stackoverflow posts I've found the solution:

```
private static Object getWithDotNotation(Document doc, String key)
            throws MongoException {

        String[] keys = key.split("\\.");

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
            Object o = doc.get(keys[i]);
            if (o == null) {
                throw new MongoException(String.format(
                        "Field '%s' does not exist or is not a Document", keys[i]));
            }
            if (o instanceof ArrayList) {
                ArrayList<?> docArrayNested = (ArrayList<?>) o;
                for (Object docNestedObj : docArrayNested) {
                    if (docNestedObj instanceof Document) {
                        doc = (Document) docNestedObj;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                doc = (Document) o;
            }
        }
        return doc.get(keys[keys.length - 1]);
    }
```

And this is my function to iterate over keys and values using dot notation:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("item.fruit.apples.type", "macintosh");

        FindIterable<Document> iterable = c.find(query);

        map.forEach((key, value) -> {

            for (Document doc : iterable) {
                Object expectedValue = map.get(key);
                Object actualValue;

                actualValue = getWithDotNotation(doc, key);

                if (!actualValue.equals(expectedValue)) {
                    System.out.println("Verification Failed:: Expected value for " + key + ": " + expectedValue + ". Actual value: " + actualValue);
                    Assert.assertTrue(false);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Verification passed:: " + key + ": " + actualValue);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```